# epsilon delta continuous function

Tags: real-analysis

$f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ continuous function and $f(x) \ge 2$ for every $x \neq 0$ Show that $f(0) \ge 2$.

I've tried to build a contradiction and epsilon/delta for continuity at 0, but not entirely sure how I can get a decent proof out of it.

Answer (score 2):

Use sequences: $x_n:=\frac{1}{n} \to 0$. From $f(x_n) \ge 2$ we get ,by  continuity,

$f(0) = \lim_{n \to \infty}f(x_n) \ge 2$

Answer (score 2):

$f^{-1}(\,(-\infty,2)\,)$ is, by continuity, an open set. By assumption, it maximally contains the point $0$. Since $\{0\}$ is not open in $\Bbb R$ with standard topology, this pre-image has to be the empty set.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $f(0) = a < 2$. Then $2-a > 0$.

Continuity in $x=0$ says that $\forall \varepsilon > 0: \exists \delta > 0$ such that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, whenever $|x-0| < \delta$, then $|f(0) - f(x)| < \varepsilon$.

So choose $\varepsilon = 2-a > 0$. Then there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x$ with $|x| < \delta$, $|f(0) - f(x)| < 2-a$.

Now pick any $x = \frac{\delta}{2}$. We know that $f(x) \geq 2$ hence
$$|f(0) - f(x)| = f(x) - f(0) = f(x) - a \geq 2-a = \varepsilon$$

This contradicts $f$ being continuous in $x = 0$.